# How to create a nested list with list comprehensions

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I want to generate a nested 2 level list from the input numbers. The end of the line is 'enter'.

```
a = [[i for i in input().split()] for i in input().split (sep = '\ n')]
```

In this case, this takes only the second line.
For example:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

It will output like this:

```
[['4', '5', '6']]
```

I want to get the final result like this:

```
[['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']]
```

Help find a mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Is the space between `\\` and `n` in `'\ n'` a typo or actually in your code?

Comment: Secondly you probably want to save your input into a string first instead of calling `input()` from within the list comprehension

Comment: How are you intending to get multi-line input in one call to `input()`?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it would be:

`[x.split() for x in data.splitlines()]`

Or if you want the items to be an `int`:

`[[int(x) for x in x.split()] for x in data.splitlines()]`

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
a = [[j for j in i.split()] for i in input().split(sep = '\n')]
```

You want the inside list to enumerate over the elements of the outside list.
Besides, remove the extra spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
`[['1', '2', '3']]`
This is almost what I need.
But it output only the first line, and the rest does not.